# Can't return false with controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm having an issue I don't understand. (I am new to php and jquery). I can not seem to get a function to return false, it will return null when passed to something in jq.

I am calling the function with this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/auth/check/",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

I have a function:

```
public function authUser()
{
    $r = false;
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $r = true;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

or within a route, both do the same thing.

```
Route::get('auth/check',function() {
    return (Auth::check()) ? True : False;
});
```

With dd i can confirm they do result in either false or true. However the response to my jq is null when it is returned.
However if i change false to something else, say a string 'test' it will return 'test'.

I can get around this by changing return to 0 when I want it to be false but I am wondering what causes this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return false as a JSON object :

```
Route::get('auth/check',function() {
     $authStatus = (Auth::check()) ? True : False ;
     return response()->json([
        'isAuth' => $authStatus
    ]);
});
```

To access it with your javascript use :

```
...

success: function (response) {
    alert(response.isAuth);
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up for me nicely!

Answer (score 0):

If you return a string instead of a boolean, Laravel should convert it into a full response and return it to the client

```
Route::get('auth/check',function() { return (Auth::check()) ? 'True' : 'False'; });
```

You can return basic string or arrays from the controller and have the response automatically generated. If you want more control, you can create the `response` object yourself. You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#creating-responses).